# Bibliography with biber backed has weird dot, and first author name has an extra comma

Tags: biblatex, biber, authoryear

I am using Overleaf, and this is my preamble for the bibliography setup:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath} % Mathematische Symbole
\usepackage{amssymb} % Mathematische Symbole
\usepackage{graphicx} % Bilder einfügen
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[titlenumbered,ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=green,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{flexisym}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{newclude}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxbibnames=99,sorting=none,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{sources.bib} 

\begin{document}

some text here \parencite{vaswani2017attention}.

\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Bibliography}] %Prints the entire bibliography with the title "Whole bibliography"



\end{document}
```

In my .bib file:

```
@inproceedings{vaswani2017attention,
  title={Attention is all you need},
  author={Vaswani, Ashish and Shazeer, Noam and Parmar, Niki and Uszkoreit, Jakob and Jones, Llion and Gomez, Aidan N and Kaiser, {\L}ukasz and Polosukhin, Illia},
  booktitle={Advances in neural information processing systems},
  pages={5998--6008},
  year={2017}
}
```

I have to use the authoryear style, however I notice something strange in the output, the first name of the first entry in the Bibliography always has this black dot (see the attached image).

And also for the items, why is the formatting for the first author like `lastname`,`firstname`? Example:

> Vaswani, Ashish, Noam Shazeer, Niki Parmar, Jakob Uszkoreit, Llion Jones,Aidan N Gomez,   Lukasz Kaiser and Illia Polosukhin (2017). “Attention is all you need”. In:Advances in neural information processing systems,pp. 5998–6008.

But I would like it to be like this:

> Ashish Vaswani, Noam Shazeer, Niki Parmar, Jakob Uszkoreit, Llion Jones,Aidan N Gomez,   Lukasz Kaiser and Illia Polosukhin (2017). “Attention is all you need”. In:Advances in neural information processing systems,pp. 5998–6008.

This is how I print the bibliography :

```
\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={Bibliography}]
```

Any fixes for this?
[image: black dot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: what do you mean? like to paste the whole preamble?

Comment: Start the code with `\documentclass` and end it with `\end{document}`, make it as short as possible, but resulting in your error ... Then we can copy and test your code to find the error ...

Comment: ok thanks, i did that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

The bibliography seems to work well. Maybe it is related to Overleaf.

To change how names are typeset in the bibliography entries just issue the following

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
```

In your preamble

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{sources.bib}
@inproceedings{vaswani2017attention,
    title={Attention is all you need},
    author={Vaswani, Ashish and Shazeer, Noam and Parmar, Niki and Uszkoreit, Jakob and Jones, Llion and Gomez, Aidan N and Kaiser, {\L}ukasz and Polosukhin, Illia},
    booktitle={Advances in neural information processing systems},
    pages={5998--6008},
    year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,maxbibnames=99,sorting=none,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip}
\addbibresource{sources.bib} 

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}

\begin{document}
    
    some text here \parencite{vaswani2017attention}.
    
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={Bibliography}]
    
\end{document}
```